# Añadir contenido SIN el label

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario dentro de un template, y estoy intentando agregarle un botón que añada otro input SIN su correspondiente label:

```
addPower(el)   {
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;

      let power = document.createElement("div");
      power.innerHTML = temPower;
      el.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);

      power.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd").forEach(item=>{
            item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
               this.sndFrm();
            });
         });

      power.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach(item=>{
         item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
            this.sndFrm();
         });
      });

      power.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach(item=>{
         item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
            this.sndFrm();
         });
      });

      return power;
   }
```

Que corresponde a este `front-end`

```
<template  id="temp-power">
    <div class="box-power" >
        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true'>PRECIOS POR POTENCIA</label>
        <div id="tmp-pow">
            <input type="text" name="t_power" style="width:40px"/>
            <input type="text" name="v_power"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

Lo que he intentado es, poner en el div con id tmp-pow el querySelector, pero no me deja. No obtiene ningún valor y se rompe el programa.

Y no puedo cambiar la template, porque todo el programa responde sobre ella...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nada, añadir un data-name al label del html y poner este comando en el `back-end`

```
el.querySelectorAll("label[data-name=labe_power]").forEach((item,index)=>{
            if(index>0){
              item.remove();
            }
         });
```

Y lo mismo con energy